# How to exclude fields from isDirty() check?

Tags: extjs

I have a form with some fields which I submit.
One field should not be modified directly but via GUI (it is a simple expression like "A eq B" or "C contains D".

So I have 2 comboboxes (A,B,C,D), (eq, contains, not contains) and a text field.
And I write a value to that read-only field when change occurs in my comboboxes and a text field.

Problem is, form.isDirty() takes those fields into account. I want to exclude them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is probably to override either the form or the fields `isDirty` method. Depending on what you chose, it may impacts other aspects of the form handling.

See examples in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/867).

Overriding the form (see [the code of the original method](http://dev.vm/ext-4.2/docs/source/Basic.html#Ext-form-Basic-method-isDirty)):

```
var form = new Ext.form.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield'
        ,name: 'testField'
        ,fieldLabel: 'Test field'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield'
        ,name: 'ignoredField'
        ,fieldLabel: 'Ignored Field'
        ,skipDirty: true
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Is dirty?'
        ,handler: function() {
            alert(form.isDirty());
        }
    }]
});

Ext.override(form.getForm(), {
    isDirty: function() {
        return !!this.getFields().findBy(function(f) {
            return !f.skipDirty && f.isDirty();
        });
    }
});
```

Overriding the field(s):

```
var form2 = new Ext.form.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield'
        ,name: 'testField'
        ,fieldLabel: 'Test field'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield'
        ,name: 'ignoredField'
        ,fieldLabel: 'Ignored Field'
        ,isDirty: function() {
            return false;
        }
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Is dirty?'
        ,handler: function() {
            alert(form2.isDirty());
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a field to be totally separated from the form. You can set the isFormField property on the field to false.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it as:

```
var form2 = new Ext.form.Panel({
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,name: 'testField'
    ,fieldLabel: 'Test field'
},{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,name: 'ignoredField'
    ,fieldLabel: 'Ignored Field'
    ,listeners: {
        change: function(fld) {
           fld.resetOriginalValue();
        }
     }
}],
buttons: [{
    text: 'Is dirty?'
    ,handler: function() {
        alert(form2.isDirty());
    }
}]
});
```